# Create a menu list all page under category Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a category table with nested category and a page table with one to many relation ship with category.

Now I want to create a menu whis list all category and under each category show the pages of that category.
for example:
Category A
 - Page A
 - Page B
Category B
 - Sub-Category A
   - Page A
 - Page C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That shouldn't be difficult, but we don't know how your relationships are defined. Here's some code that assumes you have them already setup, just to get you going:

```
<ul>
@foreach(App\Category:with('pages')->get() as $category)
    <li>
        {{ $category->name }}
        @if ($category->pages()->count() > 0)
            <ul>
            @foreach($category->pages as $page)
                <li> {{ $page->name }} </li>
            @endforeach
            </ul>
        @endif
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: it seems you know about laravel infyom banya generator. I need your help. look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030097/how-to-add-some-textfield-in-form-register-laravel-generator-infyom

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your `Category` has `subcategories()` and `pages()` relations

**template `partials.listitem.blade.php`**

```
<li>
    {{ $category->name }}    
        <ul>
            @if ($category->pages()->count())
                @foreach($category->pages as $page)
                    <li> {{ $page->name }} </li>
                @endforeach
            @endif
            @if ($category->subcategories()->count())
                @foreach($category->subcategories as $subcat)
                    @include('partials.listitem', ['category' => $subcat]
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </ul>
    </li>
```

**main loop**

```
<ul>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        @include('partials.listitem', ['category' => $category]
    @endforeach
</ul>
```